# Edit data from a table and update in the database

Tags: php, html

I want to make a listing of the records I have in the database for a table and then edit them and give update to the database.

I was able to list all the records but when I try to edit them it only lets me edit if the primary key (contribuinte) is equal to number 0, if it is 1234 or another random number combination it will not let me. I'm also using the search box's global variable.

Code of the file pesquisa.php

```
<form action="pesquisa_cliente.php" method="GET">
<label>Contribuinte</label>
<input type="text" name="pesquisa" class="form-control"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"><br/>
</form>
```

Code of the file pesquisa_cliente.php

```
<?php

$pesquisa=$_GET["pesquisa"]; 

include("ligacao_base_de_dados2.php");

$procura="select * from Clientes2 where contribuinte like '%".$pesquisa."%'";

$faz_procura= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $procura);

$num_registos= mysqli_num_rows($faz_procura);

if($num_registos==0){

echo"<strong> Nao existem clientes com esse Contribuinte</strong><br/>";
echo'<a href="pesquisa.php" role="button" style="padding-right:0"><span   
class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm">Voltar</span></a>';
exit;

}

echo'<strong>Nº total de registo encontrados:</strong>'.$num_registos;

?>
<div class="panel-body">
<table border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tr><th>Primeiro Nome</th><th>Ultimo Nome</th><th>Email</th>
<th>Password</th><th>Telemovel</th><th>Contribuinte</th><th>Morada</th>
<th>Localidade</th><th>Codigo Postal</th><th>Cidade</th><th>Distrito</th>
<th>Editar</th></tr>

for($i=0;$i<$num_registos; $i++){
$registos=mysqli_fetch_array($faz_procura);
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['primeiro_nome'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['ultimo_nome'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['email'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['password'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['telemovel'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['contribuinte'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['morada'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['localidade'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['codigo_postal'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['cidade'].'</td>';
echo'<td>'.$registos['distrito'].'</td>';
echo'<td><a href="edita_cliente.php?
contribuinte='.$registos['contribuinte'].'">Editar </a></td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
echo'<a href="pesquisa.php" role="button" style="padding-right:0"><span 
class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-sm">Voltar</span></a>';
?>

<?php
```

Code of the file edita_cliente.php

```
<?php

$contribuinte=$_GET["contribuinte"]; 

include("ligacao_base_de_dados2.php");

$editar="select * from Clientes2 where contribuinte ='.$contribuinte'";

$faz_editar= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $editar);

$registos= mysqli_fetch_array($faz_editar);


?>

<form action="atualiza_cliente.php?contribuinte=<?php echo "$contribuinte;" ?>" method="POST">

Primeiro Nome:
<input type="text" name="primeiro_nome" value='<?php echo 
$registos["primeiro_nome"];?>'>
<br/>
Ultimo Nome:
<input type="text" name="ultimo_nome" value='<?php echo 
$registos["ultimo_nome"];?>'>
<br/>
Email:
<input type="text" name="email" value='<?php echo $registos["email"];?>'>
<br/>
Password:
<input type="text" name="password" value='<?php echo $registos["password"];?
>'>
<br/>
Telemovel:
<input type="text" name="telemovel" value='<?php echo 
$registos["telemovel"];?>'>
<br/>
Morada:
<input type="text" name="morada" value='<?php echo $registos["morada"];?>'>
<br/>
Localidade:
<input type="text" name="localidade" value='<?php echo 
$registos["localidade"];?>'>
<br/>
Codigo Postal:
<input type="text" name="codigo_postal" value='<?php echo 
$registos["codigo_postal"];?>'>
<br/>
Cidade:
<input type="text" name="cidade" value='<?php echo $registos["cidade"];?>'>
<br/>
Distrito:
<input type="text" name="distrito" value='<?php echo $registos["distrito"];?
>'>
<br/>Atualizar
<input type="submit" value="Atualizar">

</form>
```

Code of the file atualiza.php

```
<?php

$contribuinte=$_GET["contribuinte"]; 


$primeiro_nome=$_POST["primeiro_nome"];
$ultimo_nome=$_POST["ultimo_nome"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$telemovel=$_POST["primeiro_nome"];
$morada=$_POST["morada"];
$localidade=$_POST["localidade"];
$codigo_postal=$_POST["codigo_postal"];
$cidade=$_POST["cidade"];
$distrito=$_POST["distrito"];


include("ligacao_base_de_dados2.php");


$atualizar= "UPDATE Clientes2 SET primeiro_nome='{$primeiro_nome}', 
ultimo_nome='{$ultimo_nome}', email='{$email}', password='{$password}', 
telemovel='{$telemovel}', morada='{$morada}', localidade='{$localidade}', 
codigo_postal='{$codigo_postal}', cidade='{$cidade}', distrito='{$distrito}' 
WHERE contribuinte='{$contribuinte}' ";
$faz_atualizar= mysqli_query($ligaBD, $atualizar);

echo"<p> O Cliente foi Atualizado com sucesso!";


?>
```

I have another table just to delete and it also only deletes me if the contribuinte equals 0. I have the same problem in both tables
If you need any more code tell me, Thank you!

Comment: @chris85 yeah it needs to be a decimal. sql injection its not a problem this code its only for a school project

Comment: Okay, how does `pesquisa_cliente.php` relate to `edita_cliente.php`? What does `pesquisa.php` take, the `0`? (You should still fix SQL injection though so you know how to handle them in the future, and so strings/integers are escaped properly)

Comment: edita_cliente.php let me edit the records of the table in the pesquisa_cliente.php. my project is about a online store and i want to edit the table costumers but he only let me if the camp 
Contributor (contribuinte) equals to 0... if the contribuinte is equal to 1234 or 54321 he doesn't let me edit

Comment: I don't see any links/form on `pesquisa_cliente.php`, how is the ID sent?

Comment: i forgot some code sorry @chris85

Comment: Okay, on the processing page what is the value of `contribuinte`? I also wouldn't `fetch` in a loop, just loop the `fetch`... `while(..fetch..){`

Comment: the contribuinte is the primary key from table Clientes2. I am using conribuinte to search the other camps

Comment: Can you limit the scope of the question, the problem should be the submission from one form to one processing page, right?

Comment: yes the problem is why only let me edit the contribuinte=0

Comment: In which script? Simplify the code here so it only shows where the value is lost.

Comment: can i show you the website?

Comment: I wont be able to do anything with server side code from there

Comment: Sorry i think I can not explain it better, I'm not very good at php